# Input box in Contact Form7 do not align on the left

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

So I have this basic code for Contact Form 7 for WordPress. From what I saw in other examples with this basic code everything should be align on the left side. The text aligns to the left, but the boxes go all the way to the right. Anyone has any idea why this could be happening?

```
<p> Name
[text* your-name] </p>
<p>Email
[text* your-email] </p>
<p>Subject
[text* your-subject] </p>
<p>Your message 
[textarea your-message]</p>
[recaptcha]
<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Comment: _“Anyone has any idea why this could be happening?”_ - likely due to styling that gets applied from your theme ... This is not really answerable with the information you have given. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can change default layout to your own one, and then set desired CSS for that. f.e.

```
<div class="cf_name"> Name
<span class="cf_input">[text* your-name]</span> </div>
<div class="cf_name">Email
<span class="cf_input">[text* your-email] </span> </div>
<div class="cf_name">Subject
<span class="cf_input">[text* your-subject] </span> </div>
<div class="cf_name">Your message 
<span class="cf_input">[textarea your-message] </span> </div>
<div class="cf_name">[recaptcha]</div>
<div class="cf_name">[submit "Send"]</div>
```